# Unit Test PHFetchResult

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, phphotolibrary

I am trying to unit test retrieving assetCollection and assets. In order to be allowed to access my PhotoAlbums I have to grant permissions. This normally either happens during the first call of a function like `fetchAssetCollections` or manually by calling `PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization()`.

Now the question is how can I assume I have permissions when running my unit tests? Because as soon as I call `PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(withLocalIdentifiers: [ album ], options: nil)` I get a `PHUnauthorizedFetchResult`.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I just move the processing logic to a separate function and just test that.